# How to create a composite container in Sitecore XM Cloud / Next Js

Tags: jss, nextjs

In MVC, composite container like Tabs component has defined layout on each tab item and it processes on partial pages.

In XM Cloud / Headless solution, I am able to create a separate layout on my tab items but I am getting a hard time making it work in the parent tab component.

I am thinking if a graphQL can be an option but wanting to ask the community if you have any inputs how to create composite containers.

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Your questions is not clear, If you want to create a tab component, in a headless you your DataSource created in such a manner that it can cover everything, and your JSS component should be designed using this DataSource, not sure where layout came into picture in your case? or am i understanding it incorrectly?